# Fundamental group of the complex Lorentz group

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

The complex Lorentz group is defined as following, suppose $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^{4}$ are two vectors, we define a bilinear form to be
$$
(x, y):=x_{0} y_{0}-x_{1} y_{1}-x_{2} y_{2}-x_{3} y_{3}
$$
and consider the group $\operatorname{SO}(1,3, \mathbb{C})$ which is the connected component of the matrix group that preserve this bilinear form. The question is what is the fundamental group of this group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're working over $\mathbb{C}$ we can just change the signs with suitable factors of $i$; that means all of the orthogonal groups are the same, and in particular (the connected component of) this one is $SO(4, \mathbb{C})$. Its maximal compact subgroup is $SO(4)$, and every connected Lie group deformation retracts onto its maximal compact subgroup so the two have the same fundamental group, which is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.